# php gd library image resizing function using base64_encode

Tags: php, base64, gd

resize.php

```
<?php
function resizeImg($new_width, $new_height, $get_image, $quality){
    ini_set("allow_url_fopen", 1);
    list($old_width, $old_height) = getimagesize($get_image);
    $image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);
    $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($get_image);
    imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $old_width, $old_height);
    header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
    $img = imagejpeg($image_p, NULL, $quality);
    echo base64_encode($img);
}
$new_width = $_GET['w'];
$new_height = $_GET['h'];
$get_image = $_GET['img'];
$get_quality = $_GET['q'];
if($get_quality == NULL){$quality = "80";}
else{$quality = $get_quality;}
?>
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,<?php echo resizeImg($new_width, $new_height, $get_image, $quality) ?>" />
```

the code above works only if i call the function outside the `<img>` tag but i require it to be called inside the image tag.

i have tried without using `base64_encode()` but still no luck, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your function ends with echo and returns nothing, then your function call uses echo again. Have your function `return` the value instead of echoing it.

Comment: @AlexHowansky tried that, didn't work. what i have come to conclusion is that setting the `header('Content-Type: image/jpeg')` changes the page hierarchy and so the page does not recognise the `<img>` tag. Does that make any sense to you?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [resizing image function implementation inpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44988132/resizing-image-function-implementation-inpage)

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to serve your image. One is to set the content-type header, dump the raw image data, and then reference the URL of this script via the `src` attribute of an `img` tag. The other is to embed the base64 encoded image in the HTML source itself. It appears you're trying to do the latter. If this is the case, simply remove the call to `header()`, as the image type information is already provided by the `src` attribute in your `img` tag.

Comment: i understood that and yes i am using the latter method but you see as soon as i remove the `header()`, the page dumps raw image data as a result while before it was just showing an empty image box (like image not loaded box of html).